# iOS memory is not being released, background thread

Tags: ios, xcode, memory

I have two View Controllers, one with a grid of buttons, and the second one is a detailed description based on the button the user presses.

I'm using "Mark Heap" in Instruments allocations tool and finding that my app is increasing in memory after the user sees the detailed View Controller and then presses the back button in the navigation bar. IT should result in a net change of zero for memory... I'm using ARC, xcode 4.2.1, deploying to ios 5.0+

When I load the new ViewController after the button press, I load some data images in a background thread. Is it possible that because I'm pressing the back button quickly, that data is still being loaded in the background thread and is never released from memory?

Comment: You might want to provide some more code; it's hard to diagnose given the description you provide.

Comment: If you believe that the cause may be the loading of the images in a background thread (which it could be) try placing the code that loads the images in your main thread and see if problem persists. Your code that runs in a background thread must release the memory, do you do that when the background thread ends or in any other moment? How many images are you loading? It doesn't sound right loading images in a background thread; typically you want to place long running tasks or cpu intesive tasks in a separate thread, an that thread should be responsible/manage any memory it requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the slides from the class i had that described memory cycles problem you may be facing:

what if you had the following property of a class?

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray* myBlocks;    // array of blocks
```

and then tried to do the following in one of that class's methods?

```
[self.myBlocks addObject:^() {
    [self doSomething];
}];
```

all objects referenced inside a block will stay in the heap as long as the block does.  (in other words, blocks keep a strong pointer to all objects referenced inside of them.)

in this case, self is an object referenced in this block.  thus the block will have a strong pointer to self.  but notice that self also has a strong pointer to the block (through its myBlocks proeprty)

THIS IS A SERIOUS PROBLEM!

neither self nor the block can ever escape the heap, now.  that's because there will always be a strong pointer to both of them (each other's pointer).  this is called a memory "cycle".

solution:

local variables are always strong.  that's okay, because when they go out of scope, they disappear, so the strong pointer goes away.  but there's a way to declare that a local variable is weak.  here's how ...

```
__weak MyClass* weakSelf = self;
[self.myBlocks addObject:^{
    [weakSelf doSomething];
}];
```

this solves the problem because now the block only has a weak pointer to self.  (self still has a strong pointer to block, but that's okay)  as long as someone in the univese has a strong pointer to this self, the block's pointer is good.  and since the block will not exist if self does not exist (since myBlocks won't exist), all is well!

Comment: thanks! I'm not using blocks anywhere in my code -- do you happen to have another example of when this type of problem could come up? Basically, I'm adding a lot of subviews to a UIView, and a lot of subviews to those subviews. Could that create this same strong pointer issue? Thanks again

Comment: well, the problem described here will primarily come up in terms of blocks, and i guess i had assumed you meant blocks because your subject line mentions a background thread.  memory cycles could occur if you have two other things that have strong memory pointers to one another that are not in a place where they can be released or set to nil in code.  generally, if you have views with subviews with subviews, you'll be describing a one-directional situation, and it won't be as likely.  but if you have view-controllers that have pointers back and forth to one another, that seems more likely.